# VSCode with Intel Fortran debugger: debugging window doesn't show allocatable variables

Tags: visual-studio-code, fortran, intel-fortran

I'm trying to debug fortran codes using VSCode and Intel Fortran on Windows. My problem is that I cannot see the values of allocatable variables in the `VARIABLES` window in the `Run and Debug` Tab.

The `VARIABLES` window shows the values of non-allocatable variables, but next to the allocatable variable names it shows `An unspecified error has occurred`.

I'm not sure if it helps, but I added my `tasks.json` and `launch.json` I'm using to compile and debug the code:

- .vscode/tasks.json

```
{
    "version": "2.0.0",
    "tasks": [
        {
            "label": "build using intel fortran",
            "type": "shell",
            "options": {
                "cwd": "${workspaceRoot}",
                "env": {
                    "PATH": (copied and pasted PATH from echo %PATH% on Intel oneAPI command prompt for Intel 64 for Visual Studio2022) 
                    "LIB": (copy and pasted LIB from echo %LIB% on Intel oneAPI command prompt for Intel 64 for Visual Studio2022)
                    "INCLUDE":  (copy and pasted INCLUDE from echo %INCLUDE% on Intel oneAPI command prompt for Intel 64 for Visual Studio2022)
                },
                "shell": {
                    "executable": "${env:windir}\\system32\\cmd.exe",
                    "args": [
                        "/d",
                        "/c"
                    ]
                }
            },
            "command": "ifort.exe",
            "args": [
                "/debug:full",
                "/o",
                "${workspaceFolder}\\a_intel.exe",
                "interface.f90",
                "invert.f90",
                "pvgauss.f90",
                "main.f90"
            ],
            "presentation": {
                "echo": true,
                "reveal": "always",
                "focus": true,
                "panel": "shared",
                "showReuseMessage": true,
                "clear": false
            },
            "problemMatcher": []
        }
    ]
}
```

- .vscode/launch.json

```
{
    "version": "0.2.0",
    "configurations": [
        {
            "name": "(Windows) Launch",
            "type": "cppvsdbg",
            "request": "launch",
            "program": "${workspaceFolder}/a_intel.exe",
            "args": [],
            "stopAtEntry": false,
            "cwd": "${workspaceFolder}",
            "environment": [
                {
                    "name": "config",
                    "value": "Debug"
                }
            ],
            "console": "integratedTerminal"
        }
    ]
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I am afraid you have run into a limitation of the Windows Debug Adapter `cppvsdbg` developed by Microsoft. We do not have any control over the underlying issue, Intel would have to step up and provide a Debug Adapter for Windows.

For more on the matter you can read through this GitHub issue: https://github.com/fortran-lang/vscode-fortran-support/issues/310

You can also follow this thread in Fortran-lang for any updates: https://fortran-lang.discourse.group/t/debugging-intel-compiled-code-on-windows-visual-studio-code/4426

As a workaround you can use WSL and Intel's GDB debugger with the `cppgdb` Debug Adapter in VS Code.

---

Full disclosure I am one of the authors of Modern Fortran for VS Code